# Java: Test for duplicate Objects in a Collection

Tags: java, collections, testing, equality

Given a `List` of `MyClass` objects (and a custom `Comparitor myComparitor` if needed), what good options are there for checking if the `List` contains two "equal" objects?

*Edit: if there are duplicates, return a reference to one or more of the duplicates.*

Overriding `MyClass.equals(MyClass)` in this case is not an option.

My initial thought is to create a hash table of sorts, but I suspect that there's a non-hack way to accomplish the same thing:

`SortedSet mySet = new TreeSet(myComparitor);`
`mySet.addAll(myList);`
`// Find duplicates in a sorted set in O(N) time`

*P.S. Is there a good reference on Markdown?*

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java: Detect duplicates in ArrayList?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/562894/java-detect-duplicates-in-arraylist)

Comment: Do you need to know which items are duplicates or do you just need to know if there are duplicates?

Comment: What do you mean with "equal objects"? If equals() method inherited from Object is not enough overriding is your only option.

Comment: *P.S. Is there a good reference on Markdown?* check the right hand column while editing message.

Comment: Sorry I didn't explictly say it, but Object.equals() isn't good enough in this case.

[Edited above post: needs to return reference(s) to one or more duplicates, if any.]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the element's `equals(Object)` method does not give you the semantic that you require, then `HashMap` or `HashSet` are not options.  Your choices are:

- Use a `TreeMap` for de-duping.  This is `O(NlogN)`.
- Sort the `ArrayList` or a copy, then iterate over looking for element i equals element i + 1.   This is `O(NlogN)`.
- Find an alternative implementation of hash sets that allows you to provide a separate object to implement equality and hashing.  (Neither Apache or Google collections support this, so you'll need to look further afield.)
- Create a wrapper class for your element type that overrides `equals(Object)` and `hashCode()`, and de-dup using a `HashSet` of wrapped objects.  This is `O(N)`, but the constant of proportionality will be larger than a simple `HashSet` due to creation of wrapper objects.

When de-duping with a `Set` it is probably better to use a loop rather than `addAll`.  This is necessary if you need to know what all of the duplicates are. If you don't need to know that, then using a loop allows you to stop when you find the first duplicate.  The only case where `addAll` is likely to perform better is when there are likely to be no duplicates.

Comment: Thanks, that's a good point - I can create a copy of the List and simply sort it.  I'll probably go with this approach.


(And another good point - I can create a TreeMap keyed by a manually generated hash value.)


Thanks for the performance tip about `Set.addAll()`.  I'm re-writing code which performs in `O(N^2)` and I think `O(NlogN)` should be acceptable (if the constant of proportionality is low).

Answer (score 0):

if you already have a sorted *list*, you could just look at any element and the next element, and if they're the same you have dups.

in your question you are using a TreeSet, which would have culled out duplicates already, so if you just need to know if you *have* duplicates, just check the size of mySet vs the size of myList. if they aren't the same you have dups.

Comment: Thanks, I've edited the post above to clarify the question.  (You're right that looking for duplicates in a sorted list is simple.  The TreeSet would automatically de-dupify if I create a wrapper class overriding Object.equals(), but there's overhead involved in doing that.)