# Java Array, Finding Duplicates

Tags: java, arrays

I have an array, and am looking for duplicates.

```
duplicates = false;
for(j = 0; j < zipcodeList.length; j++){
    for(k = 0; k < zipcodeList.length; k++){
        if (zipcodeList[k] == zipcodeList[j]){
            duplicates = true;
        }
    }
}
```

However, this code doesnt work when there are no duplicates. Whys that?

Comment: What is "doesn't work" exactly? As in, what is happening vs. what do you expect to happen?

Comment: duplicates has the wrong value

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java: Detect duplicates in ArrayList?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/562894/java-detect-duplicates-in-arraylist) -- It's not entirely the same but... note the use of a Set/intermediate "store" vs. a nested loop. In your case, `zipcodeList[k] == zipcodeList[j]` for every `k == j`.

Comment: He's expecting `duplicates` to be false, but every time there are more than 0 elements in the array, the loop will set `duplicates` to true.

Comment: Suggest edit your question to state `int[] zipcodelist =...` so it's clear you're using an array of primitives.

Comment: I think this the 2nd for loop needs an additional condition where j!=k

Answer (score 162, accepted):

### On the nose answer..

```
duplicates=false;
for (j=0;j<zipcodeList.length;j++)
  for (k=j+1;k<zipcodeList.length;k++)
    if (k!=j && zipcodeList[k] == zipcodeList[j])
      duplicates=true;
```

Edited to switch `.equals()` back to `==` since I read somewhere you're using `int`, which wasn't clear in the initial question.  Also to set `k=j+1`, to halve execution time, but it's still O(n<sup>2</sup>).

### A faster (in the limit) way

Here's a hash based approach.  You gotta pay for the autoboxing, but it's O(n) instead of O(n<sup>2</sup>).  An enterprising soul would go find a primitive int-based hash set (Apache or Google Collections has such a thing, methinks.)

```
boolean duplicates(final int[] zipcodelist)
{
  Set<Integer> lump = new HashSet<Integer>();
  for (int i : zipcodelist)
  {
    if (lump.contains(i)) return true;
    lump.add(i);
  }
  return false;
}
```

### Bow to HuyLe

See [HuyLe's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3951547/java-array-finding-duplicates/3951647#3951647) for a more or less O(n) solution, which I think needs a couple of add'l steps:

```
static boolean duplicates(final int[] zipcodelist)
{
   final int MAXZIP = 99999;
   boolean[] bitmap = new boolean[MAXZIP+1];
   java.util.Arrays.fill(bitmap, false);
   for (int item : zipcodeList)
     if (!bitmap[item]) bitmap[item] = true;
     else return true;
   }
   return false;
}
```

### Or Just to be Compact

```
static boolean duplicates(final int[] zipcodelist)
{
   final int MAXZIP = 99999;
   boolean[] bitmap = new boolean[MAXZIP+1];  // Java guarantees init to false
   for (int item : zipcodeList)
     if (!(bitmap[item] ^= true)) return true;
   return false;
}
```

### Does it Matter?

Well, so I ran a little benchmark, which is iffy all over the place, but here's the code:

```
import java.util.BitSet;

class Yuk
{
  static boolean duplicatesZero(final int[] zipcodelist)
  {
    boolean duplicates=false;
    for (int j=0;j<zipcodelist.length;j++)
      for (int k=j+1;k<zipcodelist.length;k++)
        if (k!=j && zipcodelist[k] == zipcodelist[j])
          duplicates=true;

    return duplicates;
  }


  static boolean duplicatesOne(final int[] zipcodelist)
  {
    final int MAXZIP = 99999;
    boolean[] bitmap = new boolean[MAXZIP + 1];
    java.util.Arrays.fill(bitmap, false);
    for (int item : zipcodelist) {
      if (!(bitmap[item] ^= true))
        return true;
    }
    return false;
  }

  static boolean duplicatesTwo(final int[] zipcodelist)
  {
    final int MAXZIP = 99999;

    BitSet b = new BitSet(MAXZIP + 1);
    b.set(0, MAXZIP, false);
    for (int item : zipcodelist) {
      if (!b.get(item)) {
        b.set(item, true);
      } else
        return true;
    }
    return false;
  }

  enum ApproachT { NSQUARED, HASHSET, BITSET};

  /**
   * @param args
   */
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    ApproachT approach = ApproachT.BITSET;

    final int REPS = 100;
    final int MAXZIP = 99999;

    int[] sizes = new int[] { 10, 1000, 10000, 100000, 1000000 };
    long[][] times = new long[sizes.length][REPS];

    boolean tossme = false;

    for (int sizei = 0; sizei < sizes.length; sizei++) {
      System.err.println("Trial for zipcodelist size= "+sizes[sizei]);
      for (int rep = 0; rep < REPS; rep++) {
        int[] zipcodelist = new int[sizes[sizei]];
        for (int i = 0; i < zipcodelist.length; i++) {
          zipcodelist[i] = (int) (Math.random() * (MAXZIP + 1));
        }
        long begin = System.currentTimeMillis();
        switch (approach) {
        case NSQUARED :
          tossme ^= (duplicatesZero(zipcodelist));
          break;
        case HASHSET :
          tossme ^= (duplicatesOne(zipcodelist));
          break;
        case BITSET :
          tossme ^= (duplicatesTwo(zipcodelist));
          break;

        }
        long end = System.currentTimeMillis();
        times[sizei][rep] = end - begin;


      }
      long avg = 0;
      for (int rep = 0; rep < REPS; rep++) {
        avg += times[sizei][rep];
      }
      System.err.println("Size=" + sizes[sizei] + ", avg time = "
            + avg / (double)REPS + "ms");
    }
  }

}
```

With NSQUARED:

```
Trial for size= 10
Size=10, avg time = 0.0ms
Trial for size= 1000
Size=1000, avg time = 0.0ms
Trial for size= 10000
Size=10000, avg time = 100.0ms
Trial for size= 100000
Size=100000, avg time = 9923.3ms
```

With HashSet

```
Trial for zipcodelist size= 10
Size=10, avg time = 0.16ms
Trial for zipcodelist size= 1000
Size=1000, avg time = 0.15ms
Trial for zipcodelist size= 10000
Size=10000, avg time = 0.0ms
Trial for zipcodelist size= 100000
Size=100000, avg time = 0.16ms
Trial for zipcodelist size= 1000000
Size=1000000, avg time = 0.0ms
```

With BitSet

```
Trial for zipcodelist size= 10
Size=10, avg time = 0.0ms
Trial for zipcodelist size= 1000
Size=1000, avg time = 0.0ms
Trial for zipcodelist size= 10000
Size=10000, avg time = 0.0ms
Trial for zipcodelist size= 100000
Size=100000, avg time = 0.0ms
Trial for zipcodelist size= 1000000
Size=1000000, avg time = 0.0ms
```

### BITSET Wins!

But only by a hair...  .15ms is within the error for `currentTimeMillis()`, and there are some gaping holes in my benchmark.  Note that for any list longer than 100000, you can simply return `true` because there will be a duplicate.  In fact, if the list is anything like random, you can return true WHP for a much shorter list.  What's the moral?  In the limit, the most efficient implementation is:

```
 return true;
```

And you won't be wrong very often.

Comment: It feels... inelegant.  Probably using a hash-based approach is better, especially if zipcodelist gets big.  This is a O(n^2), which is a pretty good definition of "doesn't scale well."  Nested deathmarches through arrays generally reeks like a long lost BigMac on a difficult-to-reach bookshelf.  Better to maintain a `Set<ZipCode>` and test one by one if the set `.contains()` the  next `ZipCode`.

Comment: Oops, @KitsuneYMG has something similar, but mine has the benefit of bailing out early when a single dupe is found.  Not sure whether `TreeSet` wins over `HashSet` in this setting, but I doubt it.

Comment: probably slightly better using BitSet: http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/BitSet.html

Comment: Yeah, perhaps, but my understanding was that `BitSet` was optimized for smallish sizes (i.e., roughly the word size on the machine) and may not scale to 99999 or whatever terribly well.  That's just vague rumor/memory, someone should verify.

Comment: Note the performance, even for a moderately short list (only 100k zipcodes before you hit macroscopic times -- I imagine the USPS processes that many before their crumpets get cold in the AM.)

Comment: Another alternative: if you're tight on space for whatever reason, you can sort your original list in place, then search for duplicate neighbors, for O(nlogn) time and O(1) space.

Comment: I think for the "A faster (in the limit) way" part and "Bow to HuyLe" part, the time complexity is the same, i.e O(n). Please look this ..>>http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11166247/why-is-the-following-two-duplicate-finder-algorithms-have-different-time-complex

Comment: @nhahtdh It is correct. If there are no dupes, each `item` flips an array element to `true` once, finally `false` is returned. If there are, at the first dupe, `bitmap[item]` was set to true by the first occurrence of `item`, the second flips it to `false`, the `if (!(bitmap[item] ^= true))` evaluates to `true`, immediately, `true` is returned.

Comment: @DanielFischer: My bad. I didn't read the whole code before commenting. I was thinking that this is the solution to "count the number of duplicates", or "listing elements that are not duplicated". For the problem of **"detecting duplicate"**, the "Or just to be compact" solution is **correct**.

Comment: `HashSet.add` returns a `boolean` so it’s not necessary to call `contains` before it. Halving the number of hash operations can make a big difference.

Comment: It is unnecessary to check `k!=j` given that the starting value of k is `j+1`, the values will never equate.

Comment: I have some doubt on the first approach. Fixed j, k=j+1 goes on the subarray [j+1, N-1] given N elements. So, j will be never equals to k as already noticed.

Comment: _Huyle answers_ is doing one hidden loop for nothing with `java.util.Arrays.fill(bitmap, false);` since every cells are already to `false` after the initialisation.

Comment: why do you check for k!=j in the "on the nose answer"? I cant see it as being necessary.

Answer (score 15):

Let's see how your algorithm works:

```
an array of unique values:

[1, 2, 3]

check 1 == 1. yes, there is duplicate, assigning duplicate to true.
check 1 == 2. no, doing nothing.
check 1 == 3. no, doing nothing.
check 2 == 1. no, doing nothing.
check 2 == 2. yes, there is duplicate, assigning duplicate to true.
check 2 == 3. no, doing nothing.
check 3 == 1. no, doing nothing.
check 3 == 2. no, doing nothing.
check 3 == 3. yes, there is duplicate, assigning duplicate to true.
```

a better algorithm:

```
for (j=0;j<zipcodeList.length;j++) {
    for (k=j+1;k<zipcodeList.length;k++) {
        if (zipcodeList[k]==zipcodeList[j]){ // or use .equals()
            return true;
        }
    }
}
return false;
```

Comment: This answer is especially helpful because this is the most easily portable to other languages (Giving it to you rather than andersoj because you beat them by 2 min.)

Answer (score 14):

You can use bitmap for better performance with large array.

```
    java.util.Arrays.fill(bitmap, false);

    for (int item : zipcodeList)
        if (!bitmap[item]) bitmap[item] = true;
        else break;
```

UPDATE: This is a very negligent answer of mine back in the day, keeping it here just for reference. You should refer to andersoj's excellent [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3951547/java-array-finding-duplicates/3951563#3951563).

Comment: +1 given the size of the space (assuming 5-digit zipcodes), great!

Comment: In what way was this negligent?

Answer (score 5):

To check for duplicates you need to compare **distinct** pairs.

Comment: I guess this should have been a comment.. but it's 6 years old so w/e

Answer (score 2):

Cause you are comparing the first element of the array against itself so It finds that there are duplicates even where there aren't.

Answer (score 2):

Initialize k = j+1.  You won't compare elements to themselves and you'll also not duplicate comparisons.  For example, j = 0, k = 1 and k = 0, j = 1 compare the same set of elements.  This would remove the k = 0, j = 1 comparison.

Answer (score 2):

You can also work with Set, which doesn't allow duplicates in Java..

```
    for (String name : names)
    {         
      if (set.add(name) == false) 
         { // your duplicate element }
    }
```

using add() method and check return value. If add() returns false it means that element is not allowed in the Set and that is your duplicate.

Comment: Please use `!set.add(name)` instead of `set.add(name) == false`.

Comment: Just different ways of representing the idea. I used "false" just to show @moby the idea of returning a false, which is not allowing the duplicate

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `==` use `.equals`.

try this instead (IIRC, ZipCode needs to implement `Comparable` for this to work.

```
boolean unique;
Set<ZipCode> s = new TreeSet<ZipCode>();
for( ZipCode zc : zipcodelist )
    unique||=s.add(zc);
duplicates = !unique;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public static ArrayList<Integer> duplicate(final int[] zipcodelist) {

    HashSet<Integer> hs = new HashSet<>();
    ArrayList<Integer> al = new ArrayList<>();
    for(int element: zipcodelist) {
        if(hs.add(element)==false) {
            al.add(element);
        }   
    }
    return al;
}
```

Comment: Hey Ferdinand and welcome to Stackoverflow! Preferably you would add a little but of explanation to your code to show how it solves the question asked :)

Answer (score 0):

How about using this method?

```
HashSet<Integer> zipcodeSet = new HashSet<Integer>(Arrays.asList(zipcodeList));
duplicates = zipcodeSet.size()!=zipcodeList.length;
```

Answer (score 0):

@andersoj gave a great answer, but I also want add new simple way

```
    private boolean checkDuplicateBySet(Integer[] zipcodeList) {
        Set<Integer> zipcodeSet = new HashSet(Arrays.asList(zipcodeList));
        if (zipcodeSet.size() == zipcodeList.length) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

In case zipcodeList is int[], you need convert int[] to Integer[] first(It not auto-boxing), code [here](https://www.mkyong.com/java/java-convert-int-to-integer-example/)

Complete code will be:

```
    private boolean checkDuplicateBySet2(int[] zipcodeList) {
        Integer[] zipcodeIntegerArray = new Integer[zipcodeList.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < zipcodeList.length; i++) {
            zipcodeIntegerArray[i] = Integer.valueOf(zipcodeList[i]);
        }

        Set<Integer> zipcodeSet = new HashSet(Arrays.asList(zipcodeIntegerArray));
        if (zipcodeSet.size() == zipcodeList.length) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Print all the duplicate elements. **Output -1** when no repeating elements are found.

```
import java.util.*;

public class PrintDuplicate {

    public static void main(String args[]){
        HashMap<Integer,Integer> h = new HashMap<Integer,Integer>();


        Scanner s=new Scanner(System.in);
        int ii=s.nextInt();
        int k=s.nextInt();
        int[] arr=new  int[k];
        int[] arr1=new  int[k];
        int l=0;
        for(int i=0; i<arr.length; i++)
            arr[i]=s.nextInt();
        for(int i=0; i<arr.length; i++){
            if(h.containsKey(arr[i])){
                h.put(arr[i], h.get(arr[i]) + 1);
                arr1[l++]=arr[i];
            } else {
                h.put(arr[i], 1);
            }
        }
        if(l>0)
        { 
            for(int i=0;i<l;i++)
                System.out.println(arr1[i]);
        }
        else
            System.out.println(-1);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Duplicates {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);
        int number = console.nextInt();
        String numb = "" + number;
        int leng = numb.length()-1;

        if (numb.charAt(0) != numb.charAt(1)) {
            System.out.print(numb.substring(0,1));
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < leng; i++){

          if (numb.charAt(i)==numb.charAt(i+1)){ 
             System.out.print(numb.substring(i,i+1));
          }
          else {
              System.out.print(numb.substring(i+1,i+2));
          }
       }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> This program will print all duplicates value from array.

public static void main(String[] args) {

```
    int[] array = new int[] { -1, 3, 4, 4,4,3, 9,-1, 5,5,5, 5 };
    
    Arrays.sort(array);

 boolean isMatched = false;
 int lstMatch =-1;
      for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {  
          try {
                if(array[i] == array[i+1]) { 
                    isMatched = true;
                    lstMatch = array[i+1]; 
                }
                else if(isMatched) {
                    System.out.println(lstMatch);
                    isMatched = false;
                    lstMatch = -1;
                }
          }catch(Exception ex) {
              //TODO NA
          }

      }
      if(isMatched) {
          System.out.println(lstMatch);
      }

}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

```
  public static void findDuplicates(List<Integer> list){
    if(list!=null && !list.isEmpty()){
      Set<Integer> uniques = new HashSet<>();
      Set<Integer> duplicates = new HashSet<>();

      for(int i=0;i<list.size();i++){
        if(!uniques.add(list.get(i))){
          duplicates.add(list.get(i));
        }
      }
      System.out.println("Uniques: "+uniques);
      System.out.println("Duplicates: "+duplicates);
    }else{
      System.out.println("LIST IS INVALID");
    }
  }
```

Comment: You realize that the question is 11 years old and it's unlikely anyone is watching.

Comment: @duffymo I think I'm a little late :D

Answer (score 0):

```
public static <T> Set<T> getDuplicates(Collection<T> array) {
    Set<T> duplicateItem = new HashSet<>();
    Iterator<T> it = array.iterator();
    while(it.hasNext()) {
        T object = it.next();
        if (Collections.frequency(array, object) > 1) {
            duplicateItem.add(object);
            it.remove();
        }
    }
    return duplicateItem;
}
```

// Otherway if you dont need to sort your collection, you can use this way.

```
public static <T> List<T> getDuplicates(Collection<T> array) {
    List<T> duplicateItem = new ArrayList<>();
    Iterator<T> it = array.iterator();
    while(it.hasNext()) {
        T object = it.next();
        if (Collections.frequency(array, object) > 1) {
            if (Collections.frequency(duplicateItem, object) < 1) {
                duplicateItem.add(object);
            }
            it.remove();
        }
    }
    return duplicateItem;
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.*;
class Example{
    public static boolean duplicate(int[] a) {
        for (int i=0 ; i<a.length-1 ; i++){
            for (int j = i+1; j<a.length ; j++){
                if(a[i]==a[j]){
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
    public static void main(String []args) {
        int[] ar={34,65,87,19,94,72,83,47,89};      
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(ar));//[34,65,87,19,94,72,83,47,89]
        System.out.println("ar is a duplicate array : " + duplicate(ar)); //false
        
        int[] br={34,65,87,19,94,72,83,94,89};      
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(br));//[34,65,87,19,94,72,83,94,89]
        System.out.println("br is a duplicate array : "+  duplicate(br)); //true
    }
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

```java
public class Rough_work {

    public static void main(String[] args){
        int arr[] = new int[]{1,2,1,3,2,3,1,4,5,4};

        int dup = 0;
         for(int i = 0; i<arr.length;i++){
             for(int j =i+1; j<arr.length;j++){
                 if(arr[i] == arr[j]){
                     System.out.print(arr[i]);
                     break;
                 }
             }
         }

    }
}
```