# Find duplicates in an array and return the duplicates in a temp array

Tags: java, arrays, duplicates

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Java Array, Finding Duplicates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3951547/java-array-finding-duplicates)

```
arr=[3,4,1,2,1,5,2]
```

How do i find the duplicates in this array and then return the duplicates in an array?

In the case the result should be `result [1,2]`

I am programming in Java.

Comment: Is this homework? What have you done so far?

Comment: show us some code and the issues you are dealing with.

Comment: We won't solve the problem for you. But if you are stuck trying to do something, we can help. What have you tried? What hasn't worked?

Comment: Do you want the strategy or the code? Try developing a strategy on your own. It will be similar to how you would do the same task, if asked to be done manually.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend taking the following steps:

1) Create a `HashSeta`. The `HashSet` will contain integers you have read.

2) Iterate through the entire array [0 ... size - 1]. Keep track of what index you are at with an `index` variable.

3) In each iteration, do a `HashSet.contains(arr[index])` operation. If it is true, it is a duplicate. Save this integer somewhere. Add `arr[index]` to the set.

4) Return the `HashSet` as the result.

Comment: For this to work, you'd need 2 HashSets: one to keep track of numbers seen and another to store unique duplicates. You'd return the latter HashSet.

Comment: @Doug,

"3) In each iteration, do a HashSet.contains(index) operation. If it is true, it is a duplicate. Save this integer somewhere."

In this, by 'index' you mean the Object at the current location or the location itself?

Answer (score 0):

Use nested for loop. take the first element and compare it with all the array. and then send the duplicated ones to a new array by using if/else logic.

I am not giving a code block because it is tagged as homework.