# how can i count repeated strings in Array in java?

Tags: java

I want to count strings that are repeated more than one in String Array in java. One way is to find string like that

```
String[] Array=new String[10];
String find;
System.out.print("Enter Strings for Array: ");

for(int i=0;i<Array.length;i++ ) {
    Array[i]=input.next();
}

System.out.print("Enter String to find");
find=input.next();

for(int i=0;i<Array.length;i++) {
    if(find.equals(Array[i]) {
        System.out.print("Found!");
    else
        System.out.print("Not Found!");
    }
}
```

But i want to search repeated strings through a loop and find repeated strings itself  without getting input from user to find.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java Array, Finding Duplicates](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3951547/java-array-finding-duplicates)

Answer (score 0):

First issue, you code won't compile. You open a block for your `if` statement, but don't close it before your `else` statement.

Based on your post, it seems like you want the counts of words in an array. Yet, your code suggests that you are trying to find if a string exists in an array. I'll guess it's the former, and proceed. 
Instead of an O(n*n) approach, the can be done in O(n) using a `Map`.

```
String[] arr = {"ab","c","d","e","ab"};
Map<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<String, Integer>();

for(String word: arr) {
    // if word is not in the map
    if(!map.containsKey(word))
        map.put(word, 0);
    map.put(word, map.get(word) + 1);
}

for(String word: map.keySet()) 
    System.out.println(word + " occurs " + map.get(word) + " times");
```