# How to remove triplicated lines

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop

Here is the information I have

```
63974241
63974241
63974241
68936124
68936124
74513945
74513945
76343943
76343943
76343943
85028969
85028969
91809014
109367944
109367944
109367944
```

I would like to remove those triplicates but keep singletons and duplicates.
Therefore, the expect output should be as below,

```
68936124
68936124
74513945
74513945
85028969
85028969
91809014
```

Here are the script I have now :

```
for (int row = 0; row < row_number; row++) {
    if (array[row].equals(array[row+1]) && array[row+1].equals(array[row+2]) ) {                    
    }
    else if (array[row].equals(array[row+1]) && array[row-1].equals(array[row]) ) {
    }
    else if (array[row].equals(array[row-1]) && array[row-1].equals(array[row-2]) ) {
    }
    else{ 
        System.out.println(array[row+1]);
        }               
}
```

I will be grateful if any help from here.

Comment: The original array is sorted or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For each element check:

- two previous element
- two subsequent elements
- one previous and one following element

If none of the previous has a duplicate add to your results.

As an example, consider the star as the current element:

```
 A*, A, A, B, C    Don't add because two following elements are equals
 A, A*, A, B, C    Don't add because previous and next elements are equlas
 A, A, A*, B, C    Don't add because previous two elements are equals
 A, A, A, B*, C    Add because no condition is true
 A, A, A, B, C*    Add because no condition is true
```

Here is the same code:

```
// Assuming rows is ordered so that equals elements are close each other

public List noTriplicates(Object[] rows) {
    List results = new ArrayList();
    for (int i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
        boolean add = true;

        // Check for two previous
        if (i >= 2 && rows[i-2].equals(rows[i])) {
           add = false;

        // Check previous and next
        } else if (i >= 1 && i < rows.length - 1
                       && rows[i-1].equals(rows[i]) 
                       && rows[i+1].equals(rows[i])) {
           add = false;

        // Check for two next
        } else if (i < rows.length - 2 && rows[i+2].equals(rows[i])) {
           add = false;
        }
        if (add) {
            results.add(rows[i]);
        }

    }
    // Here results has no triplicates
    return results;
}
```

Note that is also possible to combine all conditions with or operator, but the code will be less readable.

Comment: Thank you for your replay and clear explaination. It's easy to understand and use.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to have 3 nested loops, but time should be O(n log^2 n):

```
    boolean triplicates;
    int[] array = initArray();

    // track triplicates. If you don't, then time is O(n^3), as you need to start over for every nested loop
    boolean[] triplicatesPositions = new boolean[array.length];
    Arrays.fill(triplicatesPositions, false); // not necessary, default is false
    for (int j = 0; j < array.length; j++) {
        if (!triplicatesPositions[j]) {
            triplicates = false;
            // no need to start from the beginning
            for (int k = j + 1; k < array.length; k++) {
                if (array[k] == array[j]) {
                    // no need to start from the beginning
                    for (int i = k + 1; i < array.length; i++) {
                        if (array[i] == array[k]) {
                            triplicates = true; // got it!
                            // remember for the future these are triplicates
                            triplicatesPositions[k] = true; 
                            triplicatesPositions[i] = true;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            // this way, you don't print the triplicates at all. If you want to print the first and second time they appear, then simply remove the if statement and print anyway
            if (!triplicates)
        }
    }
```

Elements are not required to be ordered.
Adapting [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3951547/java-array-finding-duplicates).

Comment: Is not necessary to loop three times. You can look two step over, two step back and one step back and one over to be sure, check my answer.

Comment: This is only true when the array is sorted. When it is sorted, then one loop is enough.

Answer (score 0):

If the array is ordered I'll do like this:

```
 String lastTriplet="";   
    for (int row = 0; row < row_number; row++) {
     if ((row>=row_number-2) || ( row+2<row_number && !array[row].equals(array[row+2]))){
       if (!lastTriplet.equals(array[row])) System.out.println(array[row]);
    }else{
        lastTriplet=array[row];
        row=row+2;
      }
    }
```

Comment: Doesn't work for example for list [A, A, A] it will print A, A. Check my answer.

Comment: No, it doesn't because array[0]!=array[2] so the else jump to the fourth element

Comment: mmmm.... right. I check, but it seems correct. I didn't saw the increment in the else clause.

Comment: needs some additional improuvement. But the idea is great. THe problem is that if the row is the last one or previous you don't print nothing.

Comment: Sorry Marco... it doesn't work well if the sequence is longer than a triple. For example for [A, A, A, A] it will print [A]

Comment: Right, even contemplated that scenario... :)

Comment: Changed again, remember last triplet found

Answer (score 0):

If array is ordered, then We can modify the code as below:

```
String row_data = array[0];
int count = 0;
if(array.length == 1) 
    System.out.println(row_data);
else
    for (int row = 1; row < array.length; row++) {
        if(row_data == array[row]) {
            count++;
        } else {
            if(count < 3) {
                print(row_data, count);
            }
            row_data = array[row];
            count = 1;
        }
        if(row+1 == array.length && count < 3) {
            print(row_data, count);
        }
    }
```

Below is the print() method:

```
   void print(String row_Data, int count) {
       for(int i=0; i<count; i++) {
           System.out.println(row_Data);
       }
   }
```

Output:

```
68936124
68936124
74513945
74513945
85028969
85028969
91809014
```

Comment: It doesn't print nothing for the list [A]

Comment: I have tried at my end with the given input array in question, For me it is working, I am getting the correct output. Here the print() method is printing the rows, if they are less than 3 in nos.

Comment: I modified the answer for the list with only one element.

Comment: Same problem for lists of 2 elements

Comment: sorry,,,some edge cases were missed in the solution, I tried to run more edge cases, please check once and let me know if you found more failures, I will fix it. Thanks..

Answer (score 0):

I'm not good with streams, but something like this could work?

```
Map m = IntStream.of(array).boxed().
        collect(Collectors.groupingBy(n -> n, Collectors.counting()));

array = IntStream.of(array).boxed().filter(n -> {
  long v = (long) m.get(n);
  m.put(n, v > 2 ? 1 : v - 1);
  return v > 0;
}).mapToInt(i -> i).toArray();
```

Order preserved (if 3 equal numbers are found, it will remove the last).

If you have an array like this:

```
int[] array = { 1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 2, 3, 2, 3 };
```

You'll have:

```
{ 1, 1, 2, 3, 2, 3 }
```