# Algorithm to verify if a two-dimensional array has two equals rows

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm

> Define a method in which, given a two-dimensional array, evaluates if it has at least two identical rows

I've tried to come up with an algorithm to do it but I didn't go very far. This is what I got:

```
public static boolean righeUguali(int[][] a){
    boolean rUguali=false;

    for(int i=0; i<a.length; i++)
        for(int j=0; i<a[i].length; j++)
            if(Arrays.equals(a[i],a[j]))
                rUguali = true;
    return rUguali;
```

could you help me fix this code?

Comment: What you want to do with that algorithm, what is your problem with that code?

Comment: it doesn't work. there is obviously something wrong with it but I cannot figure out what it is. It should return true if 2 rows are identical

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java Array, Finding Duplicates](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3951547/java-array-finding-duplicates)

Comment: Have you tried a debugger or some debug-output to find the problem?

Comment: You use i<a[i].length in your second for. Souldn't it be j?

Comment: You'd also need to change `j=0` to `j=i+1`; otherwise you'll check arrays against themselves.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how i would do it:

```
int[][] array = { { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 },
            { 7, 6, 8, 3 }, 
            { 1, 2, 3, 4 },
            { 1, 2, 3, 9, 5, 6, 32, 3125423 },
            { 8, 3 }, 
            { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 } };//same as first row
    external: for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        for (int j = i + 1; j < array.length; j++) {
            if (Arrays.equals(array[i], array[j])) {
                System.out.println("Row: " + i + " is the same as row: " + j+" (warning! 0 oriented!)" );
                break external;
            }
        }
    }
```

As you see, array[] is quite random, but the first row (row 0) is the same as the last (row 5) so what i do then, is to loop through the array once and in every pass loop through the remaining rows of the array. Then i compare the arrays to chech if they are the same. As you see the code prints out a message and then terminates (stoping the external loop)

This is based on a simple sort algorythm.

**EDIT #1** As @4castle pointed out in the comments, in the context of a method the break statement is not required and can be replaced by return.

Comment: Since this is in a method, you can use the `return` to terminate the loops instead of breaking a named loop.

Comment: @4castle Indeed, but i didn't really aim for a method because actually this piece of code is extracted from a project of mine. Anyways ill m ention that in my post :) **Thank you!**

Comment: Thank you very much! it fixed my problem

Comment: @Daniele I'm glad i could help! :- )

Answer (score 4):

- You need to ensure that you are not comparing the row with itself. You ensure that by starting `j` with `i+1`
- Both loops need to iterate over the rows
- The fist of the two rows cannot be the last one, otherwise there would be no second row left to compare it to.
- optimization: you can terminate as soon as you found two equal rows

Here the modified code:

```
public static boolean righeUguali(int[][] a){
    for(int i=0; i<a.length-1; i++)
        for(int j=i+1; i<a.length; j++)
            if(Arrays.equals(a[i],a[j]))
                return true;
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Thank you especially for the optimization

Comment: @Daniele: It is still **O(n²)*.*: If speed is an issue: You can get **O(n)** by using a HashSet.

Comment: It's not a problem for a small method like this I think. But still I like to discover new ways to improve my code

Answer (score 2):

By applying the simplest answer from the [near-duplicate question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3951563/5743988):

```
public static boolean righeUguali(int[][] a) {
    for(int i = 0; i < a.length; i++)
        for(int j = i + 1; j < a.length; j++)
            if(Arrays.equals(a[i], a[j]))
                return true;
    return false;
}
```

Your algorithm is breaking because `j` is seemingly there to iterate over the nested array. That isn't needed because `Arrays.equals` will iterate over the nested array. Instead, use it as the second iterator for finding if any of the other elements match the current element specified by `i`.

If you want better performance, there are faster solutions on the duplicate question.

Answer (score 1):

No one has yet mentioned that a much faster way is to sort the top-level array, and then look for two *adjacent* rows that are identical.  If the array is m*n, this will take O(mn log n) time, as opposed to all existing solutions which take O(mn^2) time.

Of course, if you can't reorder the rows then you'll need to make a copy of the array first -- but unless your array takes up > 50% of available RAM, creating the copy and then sorting its rows will still be much faster than the existing solutions.

Comment: You're welcome :) Sorting is one of those things in CS that turns out to be useful in unexpected places!