# Java: How do I determine if an array has two equal elements?

Tags: java

I am in a beginning Java course.  I created an array with length 10 using Scanner input.  Now I need to write a program that checks to see if any of the elements in the array occur more than once. Guidance greatly appreciated!

Comment: Use any generic searching algorithm.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please let us know what have you tried and where you are stuck. Although this question is very common, correct googling should def give you all the answers

Comment: Please see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3951547/java-array-finding-duplicates

Comment: Loop through the elements of the array and compare each value with all the next ones. Come back with some code attempts.

Comment: This question is currently not answerable unless the asker tells us if its an array of primitive types (where you would need to compare with ==) or of objects like Strings (in which case equals should be used).

Answer (score 1):

Following code should do it.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.*;

public class test {
    public static void main(String [] args) throws IOException {

        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

        int[] nums = new int[10];

        for (int i=0;i<10;i++) {
            nums[i] = scanner.nextInt();
        }

        System.out.println(findDuplicate(nums) ? "Duplicate found" : "No Duplicates");

    }

    public static boolean findDuplicate(int[] nums) {
        for (int i=0; i < 10; i++) {
            for (int j=0; j<10; j++) {
                if (i!=j && nums[i] == nums[j]) {
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: won't work if the array is of a non primitive type, as you would have to use equals instead of ==.

Answer (score 0):

you can  use a  nested loop like this

```
 for(int i=0;i<array.length;i++)
  {

     for(int j=i+1;j<array.length;j++)
      {
           if(array[i].equals(array[j]))
               {
                   System.out.println("Duplicate found");
               }

       }
     }
```

Comment: won't work if the array is of a primitive type, as primitives don't have equals.

Comment: it is for string i did that because  to string comparison might seem harder than comparing primitive types