# While compiling the program, I am getting ArrayIndexOutOfBound exception

Tags: java

I am getting `ArrayIndexOutOfBound` exception in line 14.

```
package str.files;

public class Duplicate {

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    int count=0;
    String s="this is a java  is program ";
    String[] dup= s.split(" ");

    for(int i=1;i<=dup.length;i++)
    {
        //System.out.println(dup[i]);
        if(dup[i].equalsIgnoreCase(dup[i+1]))
        {

            count++;
        }           
        System.out.println("The duplicate character is : :"+dup[i]);    
    }

    System.out.println("no. of occurances of the program is : "+count);

}
```

}

The exception I'm getting is :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 7
   at str.files.Duplicate.main(Duplicate.java:14)
```

Comment: Java arrays have indexes from 0 to length-1, not 1 to length.

Comment: Note: this exception does not occur when you are compiling: it happens when you run the code.

Comment: Also use `s.split("\\s+");` to split a single or multiple space.  Also you are only checking that the duplicate is the next element

Comment: **i<=dup.length** , this is where your code is doomed :)

Comment: @Scary Wombat could you plz suggest how can i check the duplicate?

Comment: see this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3951547/java-array-finding-duplicates

Answer (score 0):

You only loop to `dup.length - 1`.

```
for(int i=1;i<dup.length - 1;i++)
{
    //System.out.println(dup[i]);
    if(dup[i].equalsIgnoreCase(dup[i+1]))
    {

        count++;
    }           
    System.out.println("The duplicate character is : :"+dup[i]);    
}
```

Comment: what about element [0] ?

Comment: I don't know. His code don't start element [0] .

Answer (score 0):

Because you use `i+1` inside loop you can reach value `i` with less than `dup.length - 1`, otherwise you will go outside the bounds of the array.

Also start with `i=0` which is the start of the array.

```
for(int i=0; i<dup.length - 1; i++) {
    //System.out.println(dup[i]);
    if(dup[i].equalsIgnoreCase(dup[i+1])) {
        count++;
    }           
    System.out.println("The duplicate character is : :"+dup[i]);    
}
```