# How to check an array if a value is there twice

Tags: java, arrays

Suppose I have an array which contains the values

> String studentList[] = {Paul, null, null};

Now I wanna add another student but make sure before if the student is not already in there.

I have already a for loop which checks if the value is null and if it is then add the student.

Comment: Using the same for loop that goes through all values. Check for the current value equalling the name you want to enter. If it does, then just return out of your loop and don't perform the add

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#contains%28java.lang.Object%29

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java Array, Finding Duplicates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3951547/java-array-finding-duplicates)

Answer (score 4):

You should use a `Set`, `HashSet` as the exact implementation and convert that to array afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

Add result to a hash set

1.HashSet contains unique elements only.

```
    HashSet<String> studentList=new HashSet<String>();  
    studentList.add("Paul");
```

Comment: I don't know about that. I can do `studentList.put("101","paul");` and then there will be 2 pauls

Comment: Do not use concrete `HashSet` for declaration, always try to use the abstract which is `Set`. This helps a lot when you are passing different implementations.

Answer (score 0):

You'd be better off using a `Set`, however, you can do this:

```
    String studentList[] = {"Paul", null, null};
    for (int i = 0; i < studentList.length; ++i) {
        if (studentList[i] == null) {
            studentList[i] = newStudent;
            break;
        } else if (studentList[i].equals(newStudent)) {
            break;
        }
    }
```