# Loop returns true even when should return false

Tags: java, for-loop, boolean, return

I'm making an arraylist of numbers, appropriately

```
private ArrayList<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList();
```

and I have to check if they're all unique.  So I have this code:

```
public boolean isUnique()
{
    ArrayList<Integer> checkNumbers = new ArrayList();

    for(int i = 1; i<=numbers.size(); i++)
    {
        if(numbers.contains(i) && !checkNumbers.contains(i))
        {
            checkNumbers.add(i);
            return true;
        }           
    }

    return false;
}
```

The idea is, I have to take in a square number (n) of integer inputs, unique from `1 to n`.

But no matter what I add to numbers (`13 2 13 2`), it always returns `true`.

What's wrong with my logic here?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/562894/java-detect-duplicates-in-arraylist

Comment: Is `i` actually the number that you want to check is in the list `numbers`? `i` is going to be 1,2,3,4... to the size of numbers, not the values in `numbers` itself.

Comment: @ben_w it is.  I have to take in a square number (n) of integer inputs, unique from 1 to n.

Comment: @novalsi please edit your question with these additional details, so people can change their responses if needed

Comment: @BeauGrantham just did.  at bottom.  thanks.

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but consider using a Set instead of a List for checkNumbers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if the list can contain more numbers than n and all you want is to verify that 1 .. n all exist and without duplication, then your code should be modified to this:

```
public boolean isUnique()
{
    ArrayList<Integer> checkNumbers = new ArrayList();

    for(int i = 1; i<=numbers.size(); i++)
    {
        if(numbers.contains(i))
        {
           if (!checkNumbers.contains(i)) 
             checkNumbers.add(i);
           else 
            return false; 
        }
        else{
            return false;
        }           
    }

    return true;
}
```

if on the other hand the list can't contain more than n elements, you don't need the other list at all:

```
public boolean isUnique()
    {

     if (numbers.size()<n)
        return false;  

        for(int i = 1; i<=numbers.size(); i++)
        {
            if(!numbers.contains(i))
              return false; 

        }

        return true;
    }
```

Comment: PERFECT!  Thank you, I see what you've done.  This is excellent.

I used the first snippet, because I have to allow user input until the user breaks it, then I have to count however many they've put in.

Answer (score 2):

You need to iterate the content of `numbers`, not their indexes.

Comment: sorry, edited to reflect that i do in fact need their indices.

Answer (score 0):

You are checking if the list contains a value equal to the indexes, not numbers in the list. You need to `get()` the value at the index (or use a foreach loop).

You also have a return statement right after you add a number to `checkNumbers`, so the list will go out of scope immediately after you add the first number to it. Therefore, it will never contain a number when you do the if evaluation.

Answer (score 0):

`checkNumbers` is always empty to begin with, so the first time it finds a value of `i` that's in your list, it's going to add that number to `checkNumbers` and then `return true`.

I'd inverse the logic - the first time it finds a number that's in the list AND in `checkNumbers`, return false. If that never happens, return true.

Answer (score 0):

The reason for your method returning true is that you create your `checkNumbers` inside it, so it's empty. It does not matter what you put into numbers - it will not be found in `checkNumbers`, add it and return with true.

Try istantiating your `checkNumbers` with a number.

Answer (score 0):

You create a new array;

```
ArrayList<Integer> checkNumbers = new ArrayList();
```

and then in the loop you do this;

```
if (numbers.contains(i) && !checkNumbers.contains(i))
{
   checkNumbers.add(i);
   return true;
}
```

`!checkNumbers.contains(i)` will *always* be true; you just created it; its empty. So the first time `numbers.contains(i)` is `true` the method will return `true`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you compare index instead the value at the index :).

Answer (score 0):

The problem in your method is that your checking whether or not each value of `i` is in the `ArrayList`. What you have to do is use the `get()`, so you have to do this:

```
public boolean isUnique()
{
    ArrayList<Integer> checkNumbers = new ArrayList();

    for(int i = 1; i<=numbers.size(); i++)
    {
        if(numbers.contains(checkNumbers.get(i)) && !checkNumbers.contains(numbers.get(i)))
        {
            checkNumbers.add(i);
            return true;
        }           
    }

    return false;
}
```