# Java Duplicates in Arraylist

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Java: Detect duplicates in ArrayList?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/562894/java-detect-duplicates-in-arraylist)

I have a strange issue.  Im sending out email alerts when remarks get added to a form.  Basically each remarks has its own individual id, but multiple remarks can attached to certain form.

In this scenario I have 3 remarks that I added.  Two were added to 1 form and the last to a different form. So I would like it just to send 2 forms.  The email is sending out 3 forms.  I understand that 3 beans will get populated, but 2 will have the same data because 2 remarks belong to the same form.  I tried some algorithms I seen posted on here for dups in and what not, but I guess the code is not recognizing duplicate elements because the remarks each have their own id??

For iteration purposes the JSP requires I throw the list of `hotParts` into an additional `ArrayList`

This is the code..there is more to it, but this is the part that matters

Thanks

```
   try
                    {
                        List<Object> dataList = new ArrayList<Object>();
                        Set<Long> ids = new HashSet<Long>();

                        for (HotPartsRemarkBean remark : latestHotPartRemarks)
                        {
                            ids.add(remark.getHpId());  
                        }

                            for ( Long id : ids)
                            {
                                hotPart = hotPartsDAO.getHotPartById(id);
                                dataList.add( hotPart ); //List Of Hot Parts Beans
                            }


               THIS WORKS!!!!!!! :)
```

Comment: Please indent your code properly

Comment: How does this piece of code relate to the problem you are having?

Comment: @adarshr You have the ability to edit, so pitch in.

Comment: @DaveJohnston Because I pass dataList to the jsp and get 3 results, and 2 out of the 3 are identical

Comment: @ErickRobertson I was going to do that in a bit. Thanks for the edit!

Comment: @DocHoliday -1 for overwriting the original code, thus making the question nigh-on useless, plus screwing up the formatting again after I put in the work to clean it.

Answer (score 4):

- If you don't need random-access, use `Set` (`HashSet`)
- If you don't need random-access, but need to preserve order, use `LinkedHashSet`
- If you need it to be a `List`, but need uniqueness, use `SetUniqueList` from commons-collections.

Comment: I would also suggest overriding Object.equals(Object other):boolean to compare field values and ignore the id attributes.  It is also a good practice, then, to also override Object.hashCode():int to hash according to the same fields you compared in Object.equals(Object other):boolean.

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for a data structure that implicitly forbids duplicates, use a [`Set`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html).

Answer (score 0):

@gurung had a great point that I wanted to emphasize but he deleted his post (edit: looks like he undeleted it).  You are adding the same list to `dataList` each time.  Changes to `hotParts` will modify every entry of `dataList` because each entry points to the same object.  So you will be left with a `dataList` that contains N identical lists (in fact, the *same* list).

If you want each element of `dataList` to be independent, you need to create a new `hotParts` each iteration of your loop:

```
for (...) {
    List<HotPartsBean> hotParts = new ArrayList<HotPartsBean>();
    ...
    dataList.add(hotParts);
}
```

Or, depending on your expectations, you could copy the list when you put it into `dataList`:

```
dataList.add(new ArrayList<HotPartsBean>(hotParts));
```

Answer (score 0):

Implement 'Comparable' interface for HotPartsBean and override the 'compareTo' method. Then use the same algorithm that you used (probably the one where you convert from List to Set) or just use a different datastructure. This will avoid the duplicates.

Also, refactor your code and define `List<Object> dataList = new ArrayList<Object>();` as below:

```
List<List<HotPartsBean>> dataList = new ArrayList<List<HotPartsBean>>();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 try
                    {
                        List<Object> dataList = new ArrayList<Object>();
                        Set<Long> ids = new HashSet<Long>();

                        for (HotPartsRemarkBean remark : latestHotPartRemarks)
                        {
                            ids.add(remark.getHpId());  
                        }

                            for ( Long id : ids)
                            {
                                hotPart = hotPartsDAO.getHotPartById(id);
                                dataList.add( hotPart ); //List Of Hot Parts Beans
                            }
```