# Unique numbers in a Vector in Java

Tags: java, vector, unique

I should find unique numbers in Vector:

```
Vector c = new Vector();
```

Something like:

```
int[] u = c.unique();
```

How can I do this?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/562894/java-detect-duplicates-in-arraylist

Comment: @Vanithi - no, that question is about finding non-unique numbers.

Comment: But the same can be used to get unique also, using `Set`

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The easiest thing to program would be to use a `Set<Integer>`. For instance, this will print the unique elements:

```
Vector<Integer> c = new Vector<Integer>();
// add elements to c

Set<Integer> unique = new HashSet<Integer>();
unique.addAll(c);
for (Integer i : unique) {
    System.out.println(i);
}
```

Comment: Note that this will not preserve order.

Comment: If you want to preserve order, use `LinkedHashSet` instead of `HashSet`.

Comment: And if you want them sorted use `SortedSet`

Comment: +1: You might consider using a Set right from the start and drop the Vector. IMHO I would only use Vector if a library requires it. Otherwise using a plain List or in this case a Set is a better choice.

Answer (score 2):

Simply create a **Set** using this vector, and the set will then consist of only unique numbers.

Answer (score 1):

There is no specific method to do this, but here is a one-liner that is almost functionally equivalent:

```
Integer[] u = new HashSet<Integer>(c).toArray(new Integer[0]);
```

(Use `LinkedHashSet` or `TreeSet` to preserve the order and sort the elements as well.)

Creating an `int[]` is more work, and will entail an explicit loop to copy values to the `int[]`.

---

FWIW, under most circumstances it is better to use `ArrayList` instead of `Vector`.  The exceptions are when you *need* the kind of thread-safety that `Vector` provides, or if you are developing for a J2ME-based platform that is missing most of the `Collection` classes.

Comment: Of course, in J2ME, not only is ArrayList not going to work, none of the `Set`-based solutions to OP's problem will work, either.