# Check duplicate entries in a List

Tags: java, collections

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Java: Detect duplicates in ArrayList?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/562894/java-detect-duplicates-in-arraylist)

To check if a List has duplicate entries i convert it to HashSet and compare the size for any mismatch. Do you guys have any better approach?

Comment: No http://stackoverflow.com/a/562906/106261

Comment: use list.indexOf and list.lastIndexOf. It it contains duplicate objects, lastIndexOf will be greater than indexOf

Comment: @UsmanSaleem I guess this will be less efficient.

Comment: why do you store them in the list then?

Comment: @NimChimpsky [This other answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/600319/829571) is more efficient.

Comment: @assylias "the other answer" is less efficient. It takes O(n) while just converting to HashSet and comparing takes only O(1). What irks me is comparing size using if.

Comment: @qualtar "converting a list to a hashset" like you describe in your question, implies adding all the list items to a hashset: that is an  O(n) operation anyway. Except that in the link I provided, adding items stops as soon as a duplicate is found, whereas in your approach all items are always added.

Comment: @assylias : i dont add one by one. I simply use Set<String> setVar = new HashSet<String>(list); which makes it O(1)

Comment: @qualtar How do you think this is done? Of course it is O(n): the constructor will loop over the items in the list and add them one by one too the set. You can check the code if you don't believe me.

Comment: Here is the code: http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/7-b147/java/util/HashSet.java#HashSet.%3Cinit%3E%28java.util.Collection%29 It calls `addAll` which loops over the list.

Comment: @assylias : rightly said. So the constructor calls addALL() which eventually runs a loop creating O(n). Now, i DO believe ya. But, even "the other answer" will take O(n) in worst case scenario. Any better idea or i have to stick with converting the entire list to HashSet (by whatever methods)...

Comment: @qualtar the "other answer" will perform at least the same, and will perform better every time there actually is a duplicate and it is not in last position in the list. A better idea would be to use a set instead of a list in the first place. Also note that even if you have a million entries in that list, the set creation will take at most a few milliseconds.

Comment: @assylias yeah but still, technically we are left with O(n). So it leaves me with even worse state (at least i was under the disillusion that i am using O(1)), than what i started. So do i close in on O(n)?

Comment: @UsmanSaleem that's a nice way how to avoid the obnoxious flag if we are not willing to terminate the method immediately after. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

This code may break somewhat earlier if you have duplicates at the beginning of the collection:

```
HashSet<Integer> hashSet = new HashSet<>();
for(Integer i : myList) {
  if(!hashSet.add(i)) return true;
}
```

As Pshemo pointed out, the `add` method returns a `bool` whether an element has actually been added to the collection, as opposed to has already existed in it.

Comment: Although the concept is transposable, your code is not Java. [Here is a Java version](http://stackoverflow.com/a/600319/829571).

Comment: The answer above is not bad, but just has one problems: the keywords var and foreach are not valid in Java.

Comment: @Muddu This is less efficient than converting list to HashSet. Your approach is of order(n) while converting to HashSet and comparing requires only O(1).

Comment: Sorry about the Java bit, translated it to Java.

Comment: @qualtar Really? Didn't know that, thought it was O(n), since `HashSet(Collection c)`-constructor appears to invoke `addAll` on `AbstractCollection` http://www.docjar.com/html/api/java/util/AbstractCollection.java.html. Or is it a different approach I need to choose?

Comment: While adding Java must check if set already have that element so your algorithm is checking it twice. More optimized version could be `for (Integer i : list) {if (!set.add(i)) return true;} return false;`

Comment: @Mudu I checked the code for the constructor and it does call addAll() with O(n). So adding a List to HashSet won't make much difference. It's O(n) anyways (at least in worst case)..