# How to check if there are duplicate elements in an ArrayList in Java

Tags: java

I have an ArrayList actors. When I print this actors variable, I get an output of like this :

Ram, cricket, Ram, chess

I want to take only only one "Ram" instead of duplication.

Comment: Use a `Set` instead of a `List` and you're done.

Comment: same with: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15518107/how-to-check-if-there-are-duplicate-elements-in-an-arraylist-in-java

Comment: @Foredoomed I don't want to remove element. I just want to know if there is a duplicate entry in an ArrayList.

Comment: Sorry for the wrong url, it should be http://stackoverflow.com/questions/562894/java-detect-duplicates-in-arraylist

Comment: Prasad,Please see my answer to find if there is any duplicate

Answer (score 6):

You need to use a [`Set`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Set.html) instead of a `List`.

From the docs:-

> A collection that contains no duplicate elements. More formally, sets
>   contain no pair of elements e1 and e2 such that e1.equals(e2), and at
>   most one null element. As implied by its name, this interface models
>   the mathematical set abstraction.

Answer (score 2):

You may like to use `Set` instead of `ArrayList` as it stores unique elements.

Answer (score 1):

Why would you use arraylist?. Use Set.

Or if you want to know that if there are any duplicates use java.util.Collections.sort() to sort and then compare previous element to current element to find duplicates

or

```
public int getNumOfDuplicates(List<Integer> dupAraay)
{ 
  Set<Integer> yourSet = new HashSet();
  int dupFound = 0;

  for (Integer yourInt : dupAraay)
  {
   if (!set1.add(yourInt))
   {
    dupFound++;
   }
  }
  return dupFound;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
ArrayList<String> values = ... //Your values
HashSet<String> uniqueValues = new HashSet<>(values);
for (String value : uniqueValues) {
   ... //Do something
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use a Set. Specifically, I suggest HashSet if order does not matter, LinkedHashSet if you want to preserve order of arrival.

If you really need an ArrayList for other reasons, you can remove duplicates by copying to a LinkedHashSet, and then back again. That is likely to be faster than sorting and testing.

Answer (score 1):

[contains](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#contains%28java.lang.Object%29)

this is method available in array list go for java docs.