# Erasing duplicates in ArrayList<SearchResults>

Tags: java, arraylist

I have a POJO class SearchResults, that contains 4 Strings (title, number, date, status) and then all the getter and setter methods for it.

In another class I populate an `ArrayList<SearchResults> results`, is there a way I can go through that list `results` and erase any elements that have a duplicate number?

I've tried populating a new ArrayList by first passing `results` into a LinkedHashSet but that didn't work.

```
 ArrayList<SearchResults> noDup;

 noDup = new ArrayList<SearchResults>(new LinkedHashSet<SearchResults>(results));
```

I've also tried doing a `.remove(indexof())` but that didn't work either.

```
if(noDup.contains(new SearchResults("-1","","",""))){noDup.remove(noDup.indexOf(new SearchResults("-1","","","")));}
```

Any suggestions?

Edit:
 The equals() method in SearchResults (wonr refers to the number)

```
    @Override
public boolean equals(Object object){
    if(object == null){
        return false;
    }
    if(getClass() != object.getClass()){
        return false;
    }
    SearchResults result = (SearchResults) object;
    if((this.wonr == null) ? (result.wonr == null): this.wonr.equals(result.wonr)){
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: How is `equals` and `hashCode` implemented in `SearchResult`?

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I'm populating an ListView in Android with the array. I don't think you can populate them with Sets but I'll double check!

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels question seems to ask about the field `number` being the criterion for uniqueness.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java: Detect duplicates in ArrayList?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/562894/java-detect-duplicates-in-arraylist)

Comment: Your equals() method considers two objects with equal wonr fields different, instead of considering them equal.

Comment: do you want the ones that have the same `number` field to not appear in the list at all or should simply _one_ of them appear in the filtered list?

Comment: @RenéLink Did't realize that hasCode() had to be implemented as well... I'll work on that and see if it fixes it.

Comment: @shane you need to be pretty specific about what your old list contains and what, precisely, you want your new list to contain. Blindly overriding `equals` and/ or `hashCode` "until it works" is likely going to give you much bigger, harder to track down problems.

Comment: It won't fix it until you also fix the equals() method, which returns false when it should return true.

Comment: @pvg I would like it to only appear once

Comment: ok, fix your question and I think @WilliamPrice below has you covered

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The suggestions for implementing hashCode and equals are possible options, but does this single number value *truly* define what it means for these objects to be equivalent in the general case?  If not, defining equals and hashCode that way seems to be a hack.

Without altering the definition of equivalence, if in *just this case* you want to elminiate values with the same number value, there are other approaches you can try.  You didn't give us the API for your `SearchResult` class, so I'll assume there's an accessible field named `number`.

One quick way is to use a `TreeSet` which defines its idea of equivalence based on an underlying *comparison operation*.  Write a custom `Comparator` that only looks at the number field and you're good to go:

## Java 8

```
List<SearchResult> allResultsWithDuplicates = // ... populated list
Comparator<SearchResult> comparator =
    (left, right) -> Integer.compare(left.number, right.number);
Set<SearchResult> uniqueNumbers = new TreeSet<>(comparator);
uniqueNumbers.addAll(allResultsWithDuplicates);
```

As JB Nizet mentioned, if your SearchResult class has a `getNumber` accessor method you can use a function reference and eliminate the lambda expression defining Comparator:

```
Comparator<SearchReult> comparator = Comparator.comparing(SearchResult::getNumber);
```

## Java 5-7

In earlier versions of Java you must implement the Comparator class yourself.  Then it plugs into the code given above in exactly the same way.  This example assumes there is a `int getNumber()` accessor method on your SearchResult class:

```
Comparator<SearchResult> comparator = 
    new Comparator<SearchResult>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(SearchResult sr1, SearchResult sr2) {
            // Optional support for null arguments is left as
            // an exercise for the reader.
            return Integer.compare(sr1.getNumber(), sr2.getNumber());
        }
    };
```

Comment: No, the suggestions to override `hashCode` and `equals` given the info are not at all valid, in fact, they're terrible advice, committing the class to a very specific and important contract for what appears to be a one-time use. Any solution with a custom `Comparator` is better.

Comment: `Comparator<SearchResult> comparator = Comparator.comparing(SearchResult::getNumber);`

Comment: @JBNizet That's how I'd do it too (if I knew the API of the class), though I think the above breaks out the step-by-step in a way that might be easier to grasp as new material.

Comment: Fair enough. Just wanted to mention this alternative, which has less risks for bugs, and is more readable, IMO.

Comment: I'll incorporate it as a reduction. Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: I don't think java 8 is an option given the mention of Android. The other thing is, it's not clear what the result actually _should_ be. A list with no instances of any duplicates? A list with a maximum of a single instance of any duplicate?

Comment: I missed Android in the comment since it wasn't a part of the question.  Either way, all of the above can be done in Java 5+ with just a bit more verbosity.

Comment: Everything done with streams can be done in Java<8  just a bit more verbosity

Comment: "with a bit more verbosity" can probably become an actual answer given that's what the question is about and this approach is the correct one. I'm pre-upvoting this one :)

Comment: Correct the lamda expression can't be used in Android. I'm not too familiar with Comparator or the lamda expression but I'll see if I can crunch it out from your answer. Thanks

Comment: @Shane Comparators are important to understand when working with Java collections. I've updated the answer but I do encourage you to read more about them.

Comment: Just throwing them in a `HashMap` keyed by `number` is the sanest solution here, I think. `TreeSet` introduces an unnecessary complexity and performance penalty that the question does not require.

Comment: @pvg You seem to have good advice; I'd be willing to upvote an answer of yours but the increasingly scattered comments are less useful.

Comment: @WilliamPrice I think you're 87.3% of the way there, I don't think it needs another answer, it just needs one good one that you've almost written.

Answer (score 1):

Another way you can do it with **Java-8** is this way:

1) Create set of unique numbers,

2) Iterate over your list and filter by this set:

```
    Set<Integer> numbers = new HashSet<>();
    List<SearchResult> noDups = listWithDups.stream()
            .filter(sr -> numbers.add(sr.getNumber()))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score -2):

If you implemented `equals()` and `hashCode()` so that they just look at `Number` property you could build a `Set<SearchResult>` instead of a `ArrayList<SearchResult>` and you will implicitly get no duplicates (this is one of the properties of sets - they don't contain duplicates). You can still iterate over the entries in the set so you should have all the functionality you need.

Answer (score -3):

Do a stream of our list and use filter method and collect to an other list.

Comment: That would require the objects in the stream to define equivalence in a compatible manner to make `Stream.distinct()` work properly; it's shorthand suggestion for (re)defining `equals` and `hashCode` and then manually populating a Set.  See the comments on other such suggestions for why that's not the best approach.

Comment: Sorry its not distinct but filter method insted