# How to compare coordinate points (of a list) in a nested for loop

Tags: java

Having some trouble building an equals method that compares two dimensional coordinate points in a list based on distance from point zero (0,0) -equation included.

```
    public double distanceToOrigin() {
        return distance(zero);
    }

    public double distance(Point that) {
       return Math.sqrt(Math.pow((x - that.getX()), 2) + Math.pow((y - that.getY()), 2));
    }

    boolean equals(List<Point> lst){
        boolean eq = true;      
        for (int i=0; i<lst.size(); i++)//accounts for first element-to-compare. 
        {

        for (int q = 1; q < lst.size(); q++)//accounts for second element-to-compare.
        {

                if(lst.distanceToOrigin(i) == (lst).distanceToOrigin(q)))
                {
                   eq = false;
                }
            }
        }
        return eq;
    }
```

I may be over-interpreting the if statement: is there a more efficient way to compare both elements (in a single line of code)?

For reference:

```
static Point zero = new Point(0, 0);

public int getX(){
        return x;
}
public int getY(){
    return y;
}
```

Assistance heartily appreciated.

Comment: From the little piece of code shown I have no idea what you are even trying to do. if any 2 points on the list are the same distance apart return false else return true? What sort of nonsense is that? And please please please rename that `boolean x` - that is just horrible!

Comment: You probably want to write `lst.get(i).distanceToOrigin()` in place of `lst.distanceToOrigin(i)`.  And the same with `q`.

Comment: If what you are trying to do is check to see if there are any duplicates in your list reference [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/562894/java-detect-duplicates-in-arraylist).

Comment: @David Wallace Thank you very much.

Comment: when you compute distance for one set of co-ordinates, you might want to save them somewhere so that you dont compute them again and again!

Comment: @Renuka Deshmukh There's a skeleton framework for that in the program. I'll reinforce it, thanks.

Comment: Please add some examples of lists and what result `equals` method should return for them.

Answer (score 0):

Examples of lists:

```
List<Point> lst = new ArrayList<Point>();
```

The corrected equals method would appear similar to the following (somewhat clumsy implementation currently):

```
boolean equals(List<Point> lst){
    boolean eq = true;      
    for (int i=0; i<lst.size(); i++)//accounts for first element-to-compare. 
    {

        for (int q = 1; q < lst.size(); q++)//accounts for second element-to-compare.
        {

            if(lst.get(i).distanceToOrigin() == lst.get(q).distanceToOrigin()){
                eq = false;
            }
        }
    }
    return eq;
}
```

The equals method should return boolean true or false based on whether or not element-to-compare(1) is identical to element-to-compare(2).

Comment: Where is the equals method?

Comment: The equals method will be used in the main in order to determine which elements to remove.

Answer (score -1):

If you are looking for equal distances of two points you are likely better off just comparing the sum of the squares of the coordinates. That avoids comparing floats and is more efficient:

```
class Point {
    public boolean isSameDistanceFromOrigin(Point other) {
        return x * x + y * y == other.x * other.x + other.y * other.y;
    }
}
```

If I'm interpreting your loop correctly you want to return false if any two points in a list are the same distance from the origin. Here's an algorithm for doing that in one line (sort of) using Java 8:

```
public boolean areAllDifferentDistancesFromOrigin(List<Point> points) {
    return points.stream().noneMatch(point -> 
        points.stream().filter(p -> p != point)
            .anyMatch(p-> point.isSameDistanceFromOrigin(p)));
}
```